# How to add Calamares installer to ISO?

Tags: calamares

I want to build my own Ubuntu operating system. I have a customized ISO, and I don't know how to install the Calamares installer on it so that it works after burning to DVD and installing it on other hardware.  How can I add Calamares to my customized ISO?

Comment: Two Ubuntu *flavors* use `calamares` as their installer, why not take a look at them, for example, all releases of Lubuntu 18.10 have used `calamares` as the installer, but it's not alone as Ubuntu Studio ISOs that use KDE Plasma as the desktop use `calamares` as well.

Comment: While I applaud your curiosity at your age, Ask Ubuntu is a US-based site, so it has a legal requirement to restrict access from anyone under the age of 13.  You can find this in the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) link at the bottom of this page.  Hopefully you'll be able to join us soon, or perhaps you could have a parent create a separate account and ask on your behalf!  Sorry that your honesty here means we can't help you at the moment!

Comment: With the account deleted (I'm assuming by a mod), my original reasons for closure are no longer a problem.  Retracted my close vote on the question itself.